# ¿Como elimino un eventListener?

Tags: javascript

En el codigo que dejare aqui abajo explico brevemente como trato de eliminar un eventListener a un elemento pero usando el removeEventListener este no tiene efecto alguno.

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
input.type = "button"; //originalmente es un checkbox
input.value = "aceptar";
//al usar el checkbox como un button agrego un eventListener(click)
input.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let parent = input.parentNode.parentNode; //el checkbox esta dentro de un td y obtengo la fila(tr) para trabajar en sus elementos hijos
    let pHijos = parent.querySelectorAll("td");
    pHijos.forEach((h, index) => {
        if (index == 0) {
        //al dar click devuelvo el button a checkbox
            input.type = "checkbox";
            input.value = "";
            input.checked = false;
        } else {
            h.contentEditable = false; //anteriormente hice editables mis campos
            h.classList.remove("editableOn");
        }
    });
    //y lo que intento hacer es que luego de ejecutar las lineas de codigo anteriores, remueve el eventListener(click)
    input.removeEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("eventListener eliminado");
    });
    //pero el removeEventListener no me funciona
});
```

Comment: Alternativamente a la excelente respuesta de masterguru usando `removeEventListener`, puedes remover todos los eventos `click` usando `input.onclick = null`. La diferencia radica en que esta solución que te propongo borra TODOS los eventos `click` asociados al `input`. En cambio, con `removeEventListener` borras el evento asociado a una función específica.

Comment: Añadiendo un comentario, a la respuesta ya echa; para hacer un removeEventListener(), segun la [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), debes hacer coincidir los parametros del add con el remove para que pueda funcionar correctamente. Saludos

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para hacer lo que pides, puedes ponerlo en una función con nombre (y no anónima) para luego poder desvincular el evento correctamente usando dicho nombre de función.

**Actualización: Hay una segunda solución más abajo sin removeEventListener y usando la opción `once` como tercer parámetro del addEventListener**

Por ejemplo (pulsa Ejecutar para verlo en acción):

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
input.type = "button"; 
input.value = "aceptar";

function funcionAceptar() {
  console.log("Estoy a la escucha")
  let parent = input.parentNode.parentNode; //el checkbox esta dentro de un td y obtengo la fila(tr) para trabajar en sus elementos hijos
  let pHijos = parent.querySelectorAll("td");
  pHijos.forEach((h, index) => {
    if (index == 0) {
      input.type = "checkbox";
      input.value = "";
      input.checked = false;
    } else {
      h.contentEditable = false;
      h.classList.remove("editableOn");
      h.textContent = "Ahora ya no tengo la clase editableOn";
    }
  });
  input.removeEventListener("click", funcionAceptar);
  console.log("Dejo de estar a la escucha")
}

input.addEventListener("click", funcionAceptar);
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="editableOn" contentEditable="true">Inicialmente tengo la clase editableOn</td>
    <td class="editableOn" contentEditable="true">Inicialmente tengo la clase editableOn</td>
</table>
```

Agrego enlace a la [documentación de **removeEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) para más opciones.

### Segunda solución (sin removeEventListener y con opción "once")

Mirando la documentación de addEventListener en inglés he encontrado esta otra sintaxis con las explicaciones de las opciones:

```
addEventListener(type, listener, options);
```

donde entre ellas se encuentra: **once**, que por defecto es `false`.

Aquí el [enlace directo a la documentación de esta opción "once"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener?#once) (en inglés).

Su descripción (traducida) dice:

> Un valor booleano que indica que el agente de escucha debe invocarse
> como máximo una vez después de agregarse. Si es true (verdadero), el detector
> se eliminará automáticamente cuando se invoque. Si no se especifica,
> el valor predeterminado es false (falso).

Por lo tanto, podriamos eliminar el addEventListener evitando el uso de **removeEventListener** de este modo:

```
{once:true}
```

y usarlo como tercer parámetro, después de la función.

Aquí un ejemplo funcional:

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
input.type = "button"; 
input.value = "aceptar";
input.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Estoy a la escucha")
    let parent = input.parentNode.parentNode;
    let pHijos = parent.querySelectorAll("td");
    pHijos.forEach((h, index) => {
        if (index == 0) {
            input.type = "checkbox";
            input.value = "";
            input.checked = false;
        } else {
            h.contentEditable = false; //anteriormente hice editables mis campos
            h.classList.remove("editableOn");
            h.textContent = "Ahora ya no tengo la clase editableOn";
        }
    });
    console.log("Dejo de estar a la escucha gracias a la opción 'once'")
}, {once:true});
```

```html
<table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class="editableOn" contentEditable="true">Inicialmente tengo la clase editableOn</td>
        <td class="editableOn" contentEditable="true">Inicialmente tengo la clase editableOn</td>
    </table>
```

Comment: Probe de exactamente como lo dejaste en la respuesta pero en la definicion de la function esta se ejecuta antes de que le de clic, no se si es porque esta este en un forEach o porque esta siendo ejecutada dentro de un metodo.

Comment: No pongas la función en un forEach, dejala fuera, aunque no creo que ese sea el problema. Tendria que ver todo tu código para entender tu problema actual.  Si ejecutas esta respuesta aquí funciona, que es el escenario que has puesto tu mismo en la pregunta.  No cambies la pregunta, haz una nueva con el nuevo escenario en todo caso.

Comment: Acabo de agregar una segunda solución en mi respuesta que quizás te irá mejor en tu escenario. Ya me dirás.

Comment: Lo acabo de subir a github por si alguien desea colaborarme con posibles soluciones...  https://github.com/JLex11/DataTable

Comment: Acabo de probar segunda solucion que dejaste y funciono a la primera, muchas gracias

Comment: @LexxCh: aquí raramente trabajamos con código que no está autocontenido en la pregunta o la respuesta, lo siento.  Si esta segunda solución de mi respuesta no te ayuda mejor deberás realizar una nueva pregunta más completa para no desvirtuar esta pregunta actual, la cual ya tiene esta respuesta que según parece es correcta basándose en el escenario inicial de tu pregunta. Si vamos cambiando la pregunta y la respuesta esto puede ser un lio y no ayudará a nadie más. Pregunta concreta = respuesta concreta

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro pues :-).  Si esta respuesta ha solucionado tu pregunta puedes marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente para siempre.  Puedes mirar [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo para el buen funcionamiento de este sitio, gracias

Comment: Excelente respuesta; no conocía el uso del tercer parámetro.

Comment: @Triby: Es que en el español no esta traducido todo el inglés, y no salia bien documentada esa opción... en el ingles se ve aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener?#once